# Attempting to access the member of a struct through a property on an enclosing class

Tags: c#, listview

I get an error when trying to run this code. I can't seem to find the root cause.

```
    public class MyClass
    {
        public MyClass()
        {
            ListView listView;
            listView = new ListView();
            listView.Size.Width = 5; 

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following lines instead.

```
ListView lvi = new ListView();        
MyStruct ms;
ms.Width = 5;
lvi.Size = ms;
```

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
listView.Width = 5;
```

or

```
listView.Size = new Size(5, listView.Height);
```

`Size` is a struct, so accessing its property will get a copy of it; hence modifying it is not actually modifying the original struct. You're modifying the **copy** of it. So compiler complains that this is not what you intended.